# Getting `unacceptable expression` error in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I use `=Sum(Nz([field1];[field2]))` as data of textbox in report and got 
`unacceptable expression` error on this. But expressions `=Sum([field2])` and `=Nz([field1];[field2])` in other textboxes works correctly. What is the problem in first expression?
Record source of report is stored procedure.
**UPD**
Now got ##error instead of value in textbox with `=Nz([field1];[field2])` expression. It also can't be calculated?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with the Nz()... if `[field1]` is null then use `[field2]`?

Comment: @LiamH, yes of course

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is not something that can be calculated in an expression.

The other expressions are a simple running sum, or can be calculated from the data of one record.

You need to add `Nz([field1];[field2])` as column to your recordsource, and then you can build the Sum of that column.